# Swapping attributes in AD

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, attributes, swap

```
on error resume next

Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://CN=" & sAMAccountName & _
              "ou=usuarios,dc=quahog,dc=edu,dc=br")
do while objUser = true
       objUser.Put "objUser.otherMailbox", "objUser.mail"
       objUser.Put "objUser.mail", "objUser.userPrincipalName"
loop

wscript.echo "Done"
```

I am trying to swap some attributes in my Active Directory: I want my actual e-mail attribute, which happens to be `mail`, to be my `otherMailbox`. Then, I want my actual logon user name, which I believe to be `objUser.userPrincipalName`, to be also my new e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript debugging step 1: remove `On Error Resume Next` and see what breaks.

AFAICS your code has 3 issues (aside from the `OERN`):

- The loop. `objUser` is an object, not a boolean, so `objUser = True` will fail.
- The `Put` method expects the attribute name as the first parameter and the new value for the attribute as the second.
- After changing an attribute you need to actually write the changes back to AD.

Change your code to this:

```
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://CN="& sAMAccountName & _
              "ou=usuarios,dc=quahog,dc=edu,dc=br")

objUser.Put "otherMailbox", objUser.mail
objUser.Put "mail", objUser.userPrincipalName
objUser.SetInfo

WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Check out the [ActiveXperts](http://www.activexperts.com/network-monitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/usersgroups/users/) script repository for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://CN=Peter Griffin,ou=usuarios,dc=quahog,dc=edu,dc=br")

    objUser.Put "otherMailbox", objUser.mail
        objUser.Put "mail", objUser.userPrincipalName
    objUser.SetInfo


wscript.echo "done"
```

The code above works perfectly, but if I change CN to sAMAccountName I get this error:
I got this error:

- Line: 1
- Caract.: 2
- Error: 0x80005000
- Code: 80005000
- Source: (null)